# WL.nativepage.show crashes in ios 10

Tags: ios, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on MFP Hybrid Project where some pages to be displayed in native pages.
To display the content in native page, we was handling it via wl.nativepage.show.

```
WL.NativePage.show("PDFViewController", backFromNativePage, params);
```

It works fine upto iOS 8,9. But it crashes with iOS 10 and we are getting the following error.

**[PDFViewController parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Note: We are not using any method of "parentViewController" in native side.And it is not calling native methods also.

Please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: What is your MobileFirst version?

Comment: I am using MFP version 6.3

Comment: @user2201624 `WL.NativePage.show()` API has been tested on iOS 10 and We did not find any issues with it. You can find MFP 6.3 sample which uses this API [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/adding-native-functionality/ios-using-native-pages-hybrid-applications/).

Comment: Are you utilizing Swift 3.0 code in your app in any way?

Comment: no. we are using objective c

Comment: Please try the sample application. Also mention what is your 6.3 build number.

Comment: build number is 6.3.0.00-20150725-1504

Comment: Okay, you seriously need to update your iFix level to the latest... you're using a build from July 2015. Go to fix central, download the latest 6.3 Studio and re-build the app.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should first upgrade from 6.3 build dated July 2015, to the latest 6.3 build dated September 2016... More than a year apart. You can download the iFix from IBM Fix Central.

Once you've upgraded the build, try again to see if WL.NativePage fails or not. If it fails still then I suggest that you'll open a PMR and supply a test project that can be debugged.